# rfkill change on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: networking, usb

I just turned on my wifi usb dongle on a desktop with no built in. This used to work, but now gets blocked by default

```
# rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 6 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 7 wlan      phy3     blocked unblocked
```

I can toggle it with

```
# rfkill unblock wlan
```

but I didn't need to it in the past. Not sure which OS update is responsible.  At any rate how can I set the default to unblocked, other than sticking the rfkill command in some startup file?

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: No OS update is responsible. The problem you have encountered is not universal.